# Access Parse Dashboard without SSL

Tags: server

I recently created Parse Dashboard on my server.My server does't have SSL
,how can i connect without ssl

How to solve Parse Dashboard can only be remotely accessed via HTTPS using a Configuration file

Comment: where is your tested code? and any error if you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a parse-dashboard-config.json and file should contain the following code

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "serverURL": "http://example.com:1337/parse",
      "appId": "yourappid",
      "masterKey": "yourmasterkey",
      "appName": "appname"
    }
  ],
   "users": [
    {
      "user":"user",
      "pass":"pass"
    }
  ]
}
```

On terminal

parse-dashboard --config parse-dashboard-config.json --allowInsecureHTTP